# understanding STATIC_CHECK in Loki library

Tags: c++, templates, c++-loki

```
     template<int> struct CompileTimeError;

    template<> struct CompileTimeError<true> {};


    #define STATIC_CHECK(expr,msg)  {CompileTimeError< ((expr)!=0) > Error_##msg; (void)Error_##msg; }

    template <class To , class From>
    To safe_reinterpret_cast(From from)
    {
        STATIC_CHECK(sizeof(From) <= sizeof(To),Destination_Type_Too_Narrow);
        return reinterpret_cast<To>(from);
    }

    void main()
    {
        void *p= NULL;
        char c= safe_reinterpret_cast<char>(p);
}
```

Above code works fine and gives compile time error when we try to convert pointer to char .
But its not very clear how STATIC_CHECK macro works.

As per above code it should lead to following

```
STATC_CHECK(false,Destination_Type_Too_Narrow)
```

Above macro will get expanded as follows:

```
CompileTimeError<false>
ERROR_Destination_Type_Too_Narrow;
(void)ERROR_Destination_Type_Too_Narrow;
```

In above macro I am not able to understand what these two statements are meant for

```
 ERROR_Destination_Type_Too_Narrow;
    (void)ERROR_Destination_Type_Too_Narrow;
```

If anyone having clear understanding please explain

Comment: Thats what I am doing right now and now able to understand this and posting it here. Is it wrong to clarify my doubt here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have specialization for class `CompileTimeError<true>`, that has default constructor. Instanciations of other cases will cause error, that `CompileTimeError<not true>` is undefined type (in your case we trying to create variable `ERROR_Destination_Type_Too_Narrow` of type `CompileTimeError<false>`). `(void)VariableName` is only silence of -Wunused

Comment: but why here we have two similar statements . C++ doesnot allow any statement without type so ERROR_Destination_Type_Too_Narrow; is illegal?

Comment: @Alien01 we have no two similar statements. First is declaration of variable. Second is usage of variable.

Comment: @Alien can. if we don't want -Wunused warning.

Comment: @Alien01 it uses for silence -Wunused. With -Wunused enable we get following warning Unused variable «Error_Destination_Type_Too_Narrow» [-Wunused-variable] in gcc.

Comment: just to clear as mentioned in modern C++ design , intention of this program is to get compile time error for this conversion..but why we need unused variable warning and in which scenario?

Comment: @Alien01 if this warning is enabled, then it will shows, but if we have (void)VariableName string, warning will not shown.

Comment: thanks forever for explaining all this but still this is unclear to me why we need Unused variable warning..

Comment: @Alien01 if you define a variable (e.g. `int a;`) and never use it, it is an error in normal cases. So Warning about unused variables is good because they very, very rarely make sense. In the case of the STATIC_CHECK macro the sole definition of the variable is its only purpose - to let the compiler check if it can instantiate the template. So this time it is on purpose that the variable `ERROR_Destination_Type_Too_Narrow` is defined but never used. But the compiler won't know that and issue that warning, so one has to fake-use the variable by casting it to void.

Comment: @Arne  if we define and variable and not use it then its not an error..compiler just gives warning...

Comment: Well, it's not an error in the "compiler emits an error" sense. But it is in the sense of "it's just nonsense". What I wanted to say is: *normally* defining a variable and never using it is just plain nonsense. There are exceptions, like scope guards, locks and other RAII related objects whose funcionality is covered by constructor and destructor alone. And `CompileTimeError<>`, of course. That's the reason why the compiler only emits a warning instead of saying "<ERROR> - Not using a variable is plain nonsense, d'oh!"